# Bicycle Socks for Road Rides

Tags: clothes

There are so many styles of socks.  Plus there are always debates on the best looking socks for group road rides.  White, black, short, tall, logos, etc.....  Some old school road purists say that black socks are for mtb only.

How do go about picking the best style? Is there any reason to prefer one style over another? Are there other properties of socks that matter?

Comment: I'm speechless!! SOCKS!!!

Comment: Obey the rules ;-) [rule #27](http://www.velominati.com/blog/the-rules/#27) (and #28) See also http://www.rapha.cc/pro-team-socks-1

Comment: I'd vote to close if I had the reputation--seems subjective and argumentative.  You're not asking about the qualities of the socks, but rather about peoples opinion of their visual appearance.

Comment: @STW - I'd agree, this question is very silly. But have a look at [this answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5016/bicycle-socks-for-road-rides/5019#5019) before condemning the page, I think it's quite practical and good advice.

Comment: Have edited your question a bit. I think my changes make the question more answerable, but please revert my edit if it's not acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend socks that can breathe easily and that absorb and wick away sweat.  That means probably not cotton athletic socks you'd get in bulk at a warehouse store.

Personal preference determines the coloration and logos, and if you're worried about style, get socks that match your kit and your shoes.

Also if your alma mater has a cycling team, contact them and see if you can buy team socks.  You'll be able to show school pride wherever you're riding, and they'll be quality.

Answer (score 2):

Find socks that *you* like the look of, that are comfortable for *you*, and fit in *your* price range. And don't worry about the rest -- they are socks after all.

Comment: And when you find socks you like, buy 5-10 pair.  You'll probably never be able to find them again.

Comment: @Daniel +1 -- this is so true!

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally socks when road racing were white, so as to aid visibility (white things moving up and down).  My local governing body had a rule when I first started racing as an amateur (perhaps they still do) that socks had to be white (and knicks completely black!).
I still feel that when possible, go for white.  I have taken to using tennis style anklet socks, particularly in summer ([rules are made to be broken](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5016/bicycle-socks-for-road-rides/5077#5077)).
In winter I use a local wool/nylon sock called ["Explorers"](http://www.holeproofexplorer.com.au/shop/men/socks/explorer/original-s1138.html) that help to keep my feet warmer for longer and still come in reasonably bright colours.

Answer (score 0):

I wear only CoolMax socks.  I find they do a good job of keeping my feet dry and non-sweaty, and they don't tend to mat -- they maintain some "loft" and padding ability, even after hours of riding.  They also wear like iron.  The only down-side is that they get dingy looking fairly quickly.

I prefer the low-rise style (just above the ankle), but that's in part because I have a mild sensory processing disorder and find high-rise socks uncomfortable in all contexts.

Color doesn't matter to me -- I generally go for muted colors because I'm color blind and can't tell what color combo looks good and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Castelli Rosso Corsa 6. they are thin, light feeling, durable, and generally have good graphic style. Graphics are always personal taste, of course.

They are a 6cm ankle. Just high enough to be certain they will not slip down, but not tall socks. They also come in a 10cm height.

Socks, in the end, are just socks, but every detail matters. I prefer the white, with black accents. Our club socks are also a custom version of this sock. It is very popular here.

[image: Castelli Rosso Corsa 6]